# javaDelegate implementation in activiti

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I am testing service task in activiti with a simple Hello world example.I created this process which will display hello world in the console,but once  i run the main i got nothing.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:class="org.activiti.Test3"></serviceTask>
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_myProcess">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="myProcess" id="BPMNPlane_myProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask1" id="BPMNShape_servicetask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="370.0" y="130.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="210.0" y="140.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent1" id="BPMNShape_endevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="660.0" y="140.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="245.0" y="157.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="370.0" y="157.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="475.0" y="157.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="660.0" y="157.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    repositoryService.createDeployment()
      .addClasspathResource("org/activiti/test/yz.bpmn")
      .deploy();
    //starting it 
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("employeeName", "Kermit");
    variables.put("numberOfDays", new Integer(4));
    variables.put("vacationMotivation", "I'm really tired!");
    RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess");



    // Fetch all tasks for the management group
    TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
    java.util.List<org.activiti.engine.task.Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("management").list();
    for (org.activiti.engine.task.Task task : tasks) {
     System.out.println("Task available: " + task.getName());
    }

}
```

}

public class Test3 implements  JavaDelegate{

```
public void execute(DelegateExecution arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("tessssssssssssst");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the process engine configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below,

```
public class Test3Delegate extends BaseJavaDelegate{
@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution delegate) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("tessssssssssssst");
}
}
```

And in the bpmn file, you can refer as delegateExpression,

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:delegateExpression="${Test3Delegate}"></serviceTask>
```

In the module context file, register this like below,

```
<bean id="Test3Delegate" parent="BaseJavaDelegate"  class="package.name.Test3Delegate"></bean>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: public class Test3Delegate extends BaseJavaDelegate do not work the compiler do not know BaseJavaDelegate

Comment: Do you have the Alfresco SDK reference for the project?